# Lemma 2.2. Lemma of Morse - Milnor's Morse Theory, application of inverse function theorem.

Tags: proof-explanation, manifolds, morse-theory

I'm learning a very tiny bit of Morse theory, from [this book](http://luis.impa.br/aulas/topdif/Milnor_MorseTheory.pdf).

> **(Lemma of Morse)** : let $p$ be a non degenerate critical point for $f$. Then there's a local coordinate system $(y^1, \ldots, y^n)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with $y_i(p) = 0$ for all $i$ and such that the identity
>   $$
> f = f(p) - (y^1)^2 - \ldots - (y^\lambda)^2 + (y^{\lambda+1})^2 + \ldots (y^n)^2
> $$
>   holds throughout $U$, where $\lambda$ is the index of $f$ at $p$.

The proof is below, written in full until the bit I don't understand.

> Proof : We first show that if there's any such expression for $f$, then $\lambda$ must be the index of $f$ at $p$. For any coordinate system $(z^1, \ldots, z^n)$, if
>   $$
> f(q) = f(p) - (z^1(q))^2 - \ldots - (z^\lambda(q))^2 + (z^{\lambda+1}(q))^2 + \ldots + (z^n(q))^2
> $$
>   then we have
>   $$
> \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^i \partial z^j}(p) = 
> \begin{cases}
> -2 & i =j \leq \lambda \\
> 2 & i =j > \lambda \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   which shows that the matrix representing $f_{**}$ w.r.t. the basis $ \frac{\partial}{\partial z^1}(p),\ldots, \frac{\partial}{\partial z^n}(p)$ is
>   $$
> \text{diag}\left(\underbrace{-2,\ldots,-2}_{\lambda \;\text{times}},\underbrace{2,\ldots, 2}_{n - \lambda \;\text{times}} \right).
> $$
>   Therefore there's a subspace of $TM_p$ of dimension $\lambda$ where $f_{**}$ is negative definite, and a subspace $V$ of dimension $n-\lambda$ where $f_{**}$ is positive definite. If there were a subspace of $TM_p$ of dimension grater than $\lambda$ on which $f_{**}$ were negative then this subspace would intersect $V$, which is clearly impossible. Therefore $\lambda$ is the index of $f_{**}$.
>   We now show that a suitable coordinate system $(y^1, \ldots, y^n)$ exists. Obviously we can assume that $p$ is the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $f(p) = f(0) = 0$.

At this point the lemma 2.1. in the book is also used, you can read the relevant statement in case since it's really simple. Continuing with the proof

> By 2.1. we can write
>   $$
> f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j g_j(x_1,\ldots, x_n)
> $$
>   for $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in some neighborhood of $0$. Since $0$ is assumed to be a critical point $g_j(0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}(0) = 0$. Therefore applying 2.1. to $g_j$ we have
>   $$
> g_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i h_{ij}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
> $$
>   for certain smooth functions $h_{ij}$. It follows that
>   $$
> f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n x_i x_j h_{ij}(x_1,\ldots,x_n).
> $$
>   We can assume that $h_{ij} = h_{ji}$, since we can write $\bar{h_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2}(h_{ij} + h_{ji})$ and then we have $\bar{h}_{ij} = \bar{h}_{ji}$. Moreover $(\bar{h}_{ij}(0))$ is equal to $\left( \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}(0) \right)$, hence is non-singular.

Now we have the bit where I need a clarification

> There is a non-singular transformation of coordinate functions which gives us the desired expression for $f$, in perhaps smaller neighborhood of $0$. To see this we just imitate the usual diagonalization proof for quadratic forms. The key step is described as follows. Suppose by induction there exist coordinates $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ in a neighborhood $U_1$ of $0$ so that
>   $$
> f = \pm (u_1)^2 \pm \ldots \pm (u_{r-1})^2 + \sum_{i,j \geq r} u_i u_j H_{ij}(u_1,\ldots, u_n)
> $$
>   throughout $U_1$; where the matrices $H_{ij}(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ are symmetric. After a linear change in the last $n-r+1$ coordinates we may assume that $H_{rr}(0) \neq 0$.

**Question 1** why can we make such assumption?
Continuing with the proof

> Let $g(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ denote the square root of $\left| H_{rr}(u_1,\ldots,u_n)\right|$. This will be a smooth, non-zero function of $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ throughout some smaller neighborhood $U_2 \subset U_1$ of $0$. Now introduce new coordinates $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ by
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> v_i = u_i & i \neq r \\
> v_r(u_1,\ldots,u_n) = g(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \left[u_r + \sum_{i>r} u_i H_{ir}/H_{rr}(u_1,\ldots,u_n) \right] & i = r
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   It follows from the inverse function theorem that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ will serve as coordinate functions within some sufficiently small neighborhood $U_3$ of $0$.

**Question 2**: How exactly is the inverse function theorem applied here? My reference for such theorem is "Theorem 6.26" of [Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Tu%27s%20introduction%20to%20manifolds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcpPaLkeXmAhW0QRUIHXNNDAcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), which I'll write down with the same notation used by Tu

> **Theorem 6.26 (Inverse function theorem for manifolds)**. Let $F : N \to M$ be a $C^{\infty}$ map between two manifolds of the same dimension, and $p \in N$. Suppose for some charts $(U,\phi) = (U,x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ about $p \in N$ and $(V,\psi) = (V,y^1,\ldots,y^n)$ about $F(p)$ in $M$, $F(U) \subset V$. Set $F^i = y^i \circ F$. Then $F$ is locally invertible at $p$ if and only if its jacobian determinant $\det \left[\frac{\partial F^i}{\partial x^j (p)} \right]$ is nonzero.

I can't really figure though how to apply this theorem.

The final bit of the Morse Lemma is to show an explicit expression for the coordinate change, which I believe I can workout later as exercise.

Can you clarify the bits of the proof I don't get?

Comment: As for Q1:  $f$ is supposed to be non-degenerate, so its Hessian matrix has full rank in a nbhd of the critical point.  If the $i,j\ge r$ part of the Hessian vanished, the crit. pt. would be degenerate.  So there is some non-zeroness in that part of the Hessian, and a linear transformation can move that non-zeroness to $H_{r,r}$.  As with $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$.

Comment: As for Q2: you have to verify that the derivative of the map defined through the equations is invertible in $0$. (It's Jacobian is nonzero). Then the inverse function theorem just tells you that, locally, the map is a diffeomorphism. Since this is purely local you only need the inverse function theorem on Euclidean space.

Comment: I don't really understand what does the author need to invert, since $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ are already explictitly defined, it's not that he defined a function of both $v$'s and $u$'s. To me it would suffice to use the fact that there's locally a transformation that diagonalize the matrix, which is known from linear algebra. But the fact that he adds the implicit function theorem on top of it means there's a subtlety I'm probably missing.

Comment: the mapping is given through an explicit formula for $v_i$ in terms of the $u_k$, for which you have to verify it is smooth and invertible with maximal rank for the derivative. This is what you need for a local coordinate system. Invertibiliy and maximal rank for the derivative are not obvious because of the defnition of the $r$th component. The standard way of verifying this is to apply the inverse function theorem. This allows you two verify both requirements by just calculating the derivative in one point.

Comment: But is the invertibilty + smoothness necessary in this context because of the "transition map" property? To prove also that the map is invertible we verify it's locally invertible for each point $u_1,\ldots,u_n$? is this the idea?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by the transition map property. A mapping which is supposed to serve as a coordinate change has to be a diffeomorphism, though. And no, the inverse function theorem tells you the only thing you have to do is to show that the Jacobian is nonzero in a single point. It will then be invertible in a whole neighbourhood. Just read your theorem 6.26.

Comment: If $(U,\phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ are two coordinate neighboors where $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ the transition map is $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$, and viceversa $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$, what I think at this point is trying to prove is to construct another coordinate system where which allows to construct a transition map, so it's invertible and differentiable. But is my understanding this is wrong, could you write a full answer?